# Get specific file inputstream from TarArchiveInputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, tar, apache-commons-compress

I have a tar file and which contains many files. I need to get a specific file from tar file and read data from that file.

I am untaring file using the below code and I will read this returned input stream using some other function.

```
 private  InputStream unTar(final File inputFile, final File outputDir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ArchiveException {
        InputStream versionInputStream = null;
        final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile); 
        final TarArchiveInputStream debInputStream = (TarArchiveInputStream) new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream("tar", is);
        TarArchiveEntry entry = null; 
        while ((entry = (TarArchiveEntry)debInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().equals("version.txt")) {
                versionInputStream =  new FileInputStream(entry.getFile());
            }     
        }
        return versionInputStream;
    }
```

I get null pointer exception when i do `versionInputStream =  new FileInputStream(entry.getFile());`

I know that we can first save this file in directory and then read the file but i dont want to save this file in directory.

Is there some way I can read this file without saving the file to some dir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no file for an entry of an archive you read. `TarArchiveEntry`'s `getFile` method only returns anything useful when the entry has been created with a `File`-arg constructor, which only makes sense when creating an archive not reading it.

The stream you are looking for is the `TarArchiveInputStream` itself after you've positioned it at the entry you want to read, i.e.

```java
            if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().equals("version.txt")) {
                versionInputStream = debInputStream;
                break;
            }
```

note the `break`.

The not-yet-released (an no, no release date, yet) Commons Compress 1.21 will contain a new `TarFile` class that provides random-access to archives read from a seekable source (like a `File`) and will make your task more convenient.

Comment: If using the same code, how do I get only the files? I want to store all the files in List<File> from the tar. Thanks